# Como faço para ler o registro das chamadas recebidas e efetuadas no iPhone utilizando o Xamarin?

Tags: c#, xamarin, ios, xamarin.ios

Como faço para ler o registro do histórico das chamadas recebidas e efetuadas no iPhone utilizando o Xamarin?

Preciso ler o log das chamadas efetuadas / recebidas no iPhone. Não sei como fazer e não encontrei material em português sobre o assunto. Alguém pode me ajudar nessa questão? Abri uma outra pergunta relacionada sobre o [registro do histórico de SMS no iPhone](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2209/ler-log-do-sms-no-iphone-xamarin).

Comment: Estou iniciando um aplicativo pelo xamarin com o iphone, preciso ler o log das ligações que cada aparelho efetua ou recebe, para mostrar ao usuário quanto tempo ele gastou com a sua ligação .

Comment: vê se ajuda, é com android, mas acho que a melhor referência [é aqui](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/949/how-to-read-call-logs)

Comment: Olá @rcaratchuk, seja bem-vindo ao Stack Overflow em Português! Dê uma olhadinha no nosso [FAQ](http://br.stackoverflow.com/about) para ver como ele funciona. Quando escrever sua pergunta, é importante listar o que você tentou fazer para resolver o problema e acrescentar detalhes sobre o que você quer fazer.

Comment: Coloquei esta pergunta (e as irmãs dela) em discussão no meta: http://meta.br.stackoverflow.com/questions/521/tres-perguntas-amplas-demais-o-que-fazer

Answer (score 10):

A Apple não tem nenhuma API no SDK para aceder a logs de chamadas.

No [Developer Center da Xamarin para IOS](http://iosapi.xamarin.com/) se usares a caixa de pesquisa, com o termo "call log" vai-te aparecer uma API, mas é para [Android](http://androidapi.xamarin.com/?link=T%3aAndroid.Provider.CallLog).

Lamento, mas com o Sistema Operativo "original" não vai ser possível acederes a esses dados.

Comment: Realmente @rcaratchuck, eu ia responder esta pergunta, mas o Zuul se adiantou. Nem essa pergunta nem a outra sobre SMS podem ser feitas no iOS sem o uso de Jailbreak. Não há API da Apple que permita isso.

Answer (score 2):

A Apple não tem nenhuma [API no SDK](http://iosapi.xamarin.com/) para acessar o registro de chamadas por motivos de segurança e privacidade: para impedir que hajam Apps que coletem informações privadas do usuário e usem ou compartilhem com terceiros.

No Android há [como fazer isso](http://androidapi.xamarin.com/?link=T%3aAndroid.Provider.CallLog) e se o aparelho tiver Jailbreak você vai poder também fazer isso, mas não é uma boa prática exigir que seu usuário tenha Jailbreak, pois esse tipo de App não é aprovado na AppStore oficial da Apple, apenas no Cydia (App Store do mundo do Jailbreak).

Infelizmente não dá para fazer isso que você precisa.