# Ler registro de histórico de SMS no iPhone usando Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, ios, xamarin.ios

Preciso ler o registo de histórico de SMS enviados / recebidos no iPhone, e o seu tempo gasto em cada envio. Não sei como fazer e não encontrei material em português sobre o assunto. Alguém pode me ajudar nessa questão? Abri uma outra pergunta relacionada sobre o [registro de chamadas no iPhone](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2208/como-faco-para-ler-o-log-das-chamadas-recebidas-e-efetuadas-no-iphone-utilizando).

Comment: acho que tu poderia juntar todas tuas perguntas em uma coisa só, elas são bastante parecidas.

Comment: Para registrar: eu não acho que esta pergunta seja duplicata, votei para fechar como "ampla demais".

Comment: Coloquei esta pergunta (e as irmãs dela) em discussão no meta: http://meta.br.stackoverflow.com/questions/521/tres-perguntas-amplas-demais-o-que-fazer

Comment: Realmente não tem nada de duplicata. O problema é outro.

Comment: Editei a pertunta para deixá-la mais clara.

Comment: @Bacco, técnicamente não é ampla demais. Ele cita a plataforma (iOS), cita a liguagem Xamarin/C# e exatamente o que ele precisa: A lista de mensagens de SMS enviadas e recebidas. A pergunta pode até ter outros problemas (eu acho que não tem, mas é minha opinião pessoal), mas não é ampla não.

Comment: @Alexandre Marcondes talvez seja mais o caso de downvote, do que fechar. O que mais me preocupa é o fato dela estar como duplicata, isso realmente está incorreto.

Comment: @Bacco isso me incomoda também. Não sei o que podemos fazer para acelerar. Os três tickets dele já estão prontos para ficarem abertos e serem respondidos e nenhum é duplicata do outro.

Answer (score 5):

A Apple não tem nenhuma [API no SDK](http://iosapi.xamarin.com/) para acessar o registro de SMS por motivos de segurança e privacidade: para impedir que hajam apps que coletem informações privadas do usuário e usem ou compartilhem com terceiros.

No Android há [como fazer isso](http://androidapi.xamarin.com/?link=T%3aAndroid.Provider.CallLog) e se o aparelho tiver Jailbreak você vai poder também fazer isso, mas não é uma boa prática exigir que seu usuário tenha jailbreak, pois esse tipo de app não é aprovado na AppStore oficial da Apple, apenas na Cidia (App Store do muindo do jailbreak).

Infelizmente não dá para fazer isso que você precisa.